# How do elemental halogens get their colour?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I learnt that in halogens the colour is due to transfer of electrons from HOMO to LUMO during excitation but I have trouble understanding what that means. Also I don't understand how iodine is blackish in solid state while violet in gaseous state.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33861/why-does-color-of-halogen-deepens-and-the-boiling-point-decreases-down-the-group?r=SearchResults

Comment: To the 2nd part, notice that dye based (= not pigment )  black colour of markers or inkjet printers is usually dark violet colour.