Colours of Halogens
It is known that the halogens have the following colours:
$\ce{F_2}$: Pale Yellow
$\ce{Cl_2}$: Greenish Yellow
$\ce{Br_2}$: Reddish Brown
$\ce{I_2}$: Violet
If we talk about predicting the colours based on their HOMO-LUMO transition energies, we may say that the $π^*_{np}$ - $σ^*_{np}$ gap decreases with increasing $n$, thus the wavelength of energy absorbed should increase and correspondingly the wavelength of emitted light should decrease as we go from $\ce{F_2}$ to $\ce{I_2}$.
However, while $\ce{F_2}$, $\ce{Cl_2}$ and $\ce{I_2}$ seem to adhere to this order, $\ce{Br_2}$ doesn't, showing up on the far end of the spectrum.
What is the reason behind this anomaly? Here's an illustration:


Are you asking about the elements in the gas phase, or for the elements in their standard states?

Standard states, I suppose. Does the phase matter though? Not sure but it seems counterintuitive for a substance to change colours just through phase change.

Furthermore, if there isn't any difference in the electronic configurations in different phases, how could there be different colours? Pardon me if I am unaware of other factors at play here as I'm only a high school student

Look at the pictures of Iodine on wikipedia - the solid is definitely a different colour from the gas. Put simply in the rarefied gaseous case you can consider individual molecules as they are so well separated from each other, while in the much more dense condensed liquid and solid phases interactions between molecules become important, so much so in the iodine case that it can be considered a semiconductor.

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33861/why-does-color-of-halogen-deepens-and-the-boiling-point-decreases-down-the-group

This is a common fallacy! What you see reflects what DID NOT happen. These colors are the light that is NOT absorbed.
